# Why won't my FloatingActionButtons show up in my map?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I've tried many different things to make this work. Here's my ui.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (lat == null || lng == null) {
      return Container();
    }
    return Container(
        child: Scaffold(key: _scaffoldKey,
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
          body:
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: nameController,
                            cursorColor: Colors.white,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Identifier';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Identifier'),
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            controller: feedbackController,
                            cursorColor: Colors.white,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Notes'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(
                  height: 325,
                  child: GoogleMap(
                    markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
                      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                          target: LatLng(lat, lng),
                          zoom: 9.0),
                      myLocationEnabled: true,
                      compassEnabled: true,
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                      mapType: MapType.normal,
                      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                        controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
                        Expanded(child: FloatingActionButton(
                          onPressed: _submitForm,
                          child: Text("test"))
                        );
                      }),
                ),
```

I want not only to be able to place FloatingActionButtons in there, but also my TextFormFields and RaissedButtons. Is it possible? I'd also like my map to cover the entire screen while everything pretty much floats on top of it.

Comment: Check your z-order. Looks like you might be drawing the map on top of your controls.

Comment: Not sure what that means. I'm new to flutter and pretty bad at this.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `FloatingActionButton` to the `Scaffold` instead of where it is now?

Comment: Also, why don't you use `Stack` ?

Comment: just tried. I keep getting cut off:          FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _submitForm,
              child: Text("test"),
          )));
        
          Center(
            child: Column(

Comment: Tried using stack. disabled my child: scaffold. what a headache.

Comment: Okay I was able to stack and now everything is a mess. :/

Comment: nevermind, i'm kind of getting somewhere now. thank you!

Comment: @Mobina Stack worked well for my buttons. However, my TextFormField's vanished. Maybe there's no way to lay them over the map?